# Return a Value from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a problem to get a value from an excel sheet. I am following the tutorial but it doesn't work. I also included Excel reference into word but still I cant return the Value
This is my Code:

```
Sub Return_a_Value_from_Excel()

Dim mySpreadsheet As Excel.Workbook
Dim strSalesTotal As String

Set mySpreadsheet = GetObject("C:\Documents\Book1.xls")
strSalesTotal = mySpreadsheet.Application.Range("Test").Value
Set mySpreadsheet = Nothing

Selection.TypeText "Current sales total: $" & strSalesTotal & "."
Selection.TypeParagraph
End Sub
```

I just want to return the value that is written in excel

Comment: Your code runs fine on my pc when I change the range `"Test"` to `"A1"`. Did you run it step-by-step and checked the variable strSalesTotal? You could also check what happens, if you change the range to the column you want to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, You should follow Excel Object Model i.e

Application --> Workbook --> Sheets --> Range / Chart

In below line :

```
strSalesTotal = mySpreadsheet.Application.Range("Test").Value
```

You skipped Sheets,
Your Code should be

```
strSalesTotal = mySpreadsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Please Replace "Sheet1" and "A1" Accorodingly

Comment: Actually, when you refer to a named range, you do not need to refer the sheet... Try to make a named range "test" and refer it like this `?[test]` from the immediate window.

Comment: It depends on the scope of the range while Defining it.

to use a Workbook level range you have to refer the Workbook with it.

Sub FormatRange() 
    Range("MyBook.xls!MyRange").Font.Italic = True 
End Sub

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx

Comment: That's actually true, @PankajKushawaha. If you define it manually, through the cell above A1, it gets the Worksheet range.

Comment: THe book "Mastering Microsoft VBA" used the exact same code. I made a value on the sheet and called it "SalesTotal". I want to call the value linked to "SalesTotal".

Answer (score 0):

Or try like this, if you have not defined it explicitly to be valid only in the sheet range :

```
strSalesTotal = mySpreadsheet.Range("Test").Value
```

or

```
strSalesTotal = mySpreadsheet.[Test]
```